# how to add toolbar to listview

Tags: android, listview, android-toolbar

i am trying to add a toolbar to a listview in android studio... i understand that listview does not support toolbar and i should use appcompatactivity. I have tried to change the listview and i get numerous errors... i have looked at about 80 different samples and cant figure out what i am doing wrong at all.... if anyone has ever used a toolbar and a listview i would love any extra help you could give....

here is my current listview code

```
package mypackage.android;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import mypackage.android.database.CommonNamesAdapter;

public class CommonNames extends ListActivity {

    CommonNamesAdapter cnTable;
    ListView cnListView;
    Cursor c;

    private static final int COMMON_NAME_ACTIVITY_START = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.common_names_list);

        cnTable = new CommonNamesAdapter();
        cnTable.open(getApplicationContext());

        c = cnTable.fetchAllCommonNames();
        startManagingCursor(c);

        if(c!=null){
            SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                    R.layout.common_names_row,
                    c,
                    new String[] {c.getColumnName(1)},
                    new int[] {R.id.commonName});
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        c.moveToPosition(position);

        Intent i = new Intent(this, CommonNameDescription.class);
        i.putExtra(CommonNamesAdapter.COMMON_NAME_ROWID, id);
        i.putExtra(CommonNamesAdapter.COMMON_NAME, c.getString(
                c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CommonNamesAdapter.COMMON_NAME)));
        i.putExtra(CommonNamesAdapter.COMMON_NAME_COUNT, c.getString(
                c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CommonNamesAdapter.COMMON_NAME_COUNT)));
        startActivityForResult(i, COMMON_NAME_ACTIVITY_START);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        //Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        switch(requestCode) {
        default: break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        c.close();
        cnTable.close();
    }

}
```

here is what i would like the code to look like but it doesnt work

```
package mypackage.android;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import mypackage.android.database.CommonNamesAdapter;

public class CommonNames extends AppCompatActivity {

    CommonNamesAdapter cnTable;
    ListView cnListView;
    Cursor c;

    private static final int COMMON_NAME_ACTIVITY_START = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.common_names_list);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        cnTable = new CommonNamesAdapter();
        cnTable.open(getApplicationContext());

        c = cnTable.fetchAllCommonNames();
        startManagingCursor(c);

        if(c!=null){
            SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                    R.layout.common_names_row,
                    c,
                    new String[] {c.getColumnName(1)},
                    new int[] {R.id.commonName});
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        c.moveToPosition(position);

        Intent i = new Intent(this, CommonNameDescription.class);
        i.putExtra(CommonNamesAdapter.COMMON_NAME_ROWID, id);
        i.putExtra(CommonNamesAdapter.COMMON_NAME, c.getString(
                c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CommonNamesAdapter.COMMON_NAME)));
        i.putExtra(CommonNamesAdapter.COMMON_NAME_COUNT, c.getString(
                c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CommonNamesAdapter.COMMON_NAME_COUNT)));
        startActivityForResult(i, COMMON_NAME_ACTIVITY_START);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        //Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        switch(requestCode) {
        default: break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        c.close();
        cnTable.close();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        boolean bRet=false;//set true is menu selection handled
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings_get_pro:
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.pro_version_url)));
                startActivity(intent);
                bRet=true;
                break;
            case R.id.action_settings_get_pro2:
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent2.setData(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.pro_version_url)));
                startActivity(intent2);
                bRet=true;
                break;
            case R.id.action_settings_app_help:
                Toast.makeText(this, this.getString(R.string.action_settings_app_help_text), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                bRet=true;
                break;
            case R.id.action_settings_about_app:
                Toast.makeText(this, this.getString(R.string.action_settings_about_text), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                bRet=true;
                break;
            case R.id.action_settings_rate_app:
                Intent intent3 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent3.setData(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.rate_this_app_url)));
                startActivity(intent3);
                bRet=true;
                break;
            case R.id.action_settings_privacy_policy:
                Intent intentprivacy = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intentprivacy.setData(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.privacy_policy_url)));
                startActivity(intentprivacy);
                bRet=true;
                break;
            case R.id.action_settings_all_our_apps:
                Intent intent4 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent4.setData(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.all_our_apps_url)));
                startActivity(intent4);
                bRet=true;
                break;
            default:
                bRet=super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return bRet;
    }


}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated i have been pulling my hair out for hours now...

Comment: what error did you get with AppCompatActivity?

Comment: setListAdapter(adapter); becomes red and invalid and so does super.onListItemClick

Comment: check my answer below

Comment: still getting errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this(Use AppCompatActivity)

```
public class CommonNames extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

        CommonNamesAdapter cnTable;
        ListView cnListView;
        Cursor c;

        private static final int COMMON_NAME_ACTIVITY_START = 1;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.common_names_list);

            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            cnListView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.cnListView);

            cnTable = new CommonNamesAdapter();
            cnTable.open(getApplicationContext());

            c = cnTable.fetchAllCommonNames();
            startManagingCursor(c);

            if(c!=null){
                SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                        R.layout.common_names_row,
                        c,
                        new String[] {c.getColumnName(1)},
                        new int[] {R.id.commonName});
                cnListView.setAdapter(adapter);
                cnListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
            //Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            switch(requestCode) {
                default: break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy(){
            super.onDestroy();
            c.close();
            cnTable.close();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

            return true;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            boolean bRet=false;//set true is menu selection handled
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_settings_get_pro:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.pro_version_url)));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    bRet=true;
                    break;
                case R.id.action_settings_get_pro2:
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent2.setData(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.pro_version_url)));
                    startActivity(intent2);
                    bRet=true;
                    break;
                case R.id.action_settings_app_help:
                    Toast.makeText(this, this.getString(R.string.action_settings_app_help_text), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    bRet=true;
                    break;
                case R.id.action_settings_about_app:
                    Toast.makeText(this, this.getString(R.string.action_settings_about_text), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    bRet=true;
                    break;
                case R.id.action_settings_rate_app:
                    Intent intent3 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent3.setData(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.rate_this_app_url)));
                    startActivity(intent3);
                    bRet=true;
                    break;
                case R.id.action_settings_privacy_policy:
                    Intent intentprivacy = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intentprivacy.setData(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.privacy_policy_url)));
                    startActivity(intentprivacy);
                    bRet=true;
                    break;
                case R.id.action_settings_all_our_apps:
                    Intent intent4 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent4.setData(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.all_our_apps_url)));
                    startActivity(intent4);
                    bRet=true;
                    break;
                default:
                    bRet=super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
            return bRet;
        }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        c.moveToPosition(position);

        Intent i = new Intent(this, CommonNameDescription.class);
        i.putExtra(CommonNamesAdapter.COMMON_NAME_ROWID, id);
        i.putExtra(CommonNamesAdapter.COMMON_NAME, c.getString(
                c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CommonNamesAdapter.COMMON_NAME)));
        i.putExtra(CommonNamesAdapter.COMMON_NAME_COUNT, c.getString(
                c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CommonNamesAdapter.COMMON_NAME_COUNT)));
        startActivityForResult(i, COMMON_NAME_ACTIVITY_START);
    }
}
```

And in the layout file change the id of listview

```
<ListView 
android:id="@+id/cmListView"
android:height="" ....../>
```

Comment: ive added appcompatactivity and changed the listadapter to             cnListView.setListAdapter(adapter); however it is still red and it gives me the error Cannot resolve method 'setListAdapter(android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter)'

Comment: oh my mistake . you should do cnListView.setAdapter(adapter). Check my updated answer

Comment: the error is gone for the but im unsure how to add the second piece of code you posted... im not sure where to put it ... do it delete the whole code from  @Override
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView to
  startActivityForResult(i, COMMON_NAME_ACTIVITY_START);
 }

Comment: yes delete that code and use my code inside onCreate()

Comment: ok ive done that but now override throws and error @Override is not allowed when implementing interface method

 and Intent i = new Intent(this, CommonNameDescription.class); throws the error Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(anonymous android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, java.lang.Class<mypackage.android.CommonNameDescription>)'

Comment: check my code again. You can google and check for the item click listener

Comment: haha you are so funny. let me change the whole bunch of code. wait

Comment: oh wow i didnt expect that thanks alot it all works except the last override ...  it still throws error Override so i set the language to 6 and tried to run the app.. the build worked o.k and the app turned on but when i loaded this activity the app shut down

Comment: log cat says 

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134996/discussion-between-ajay-shrestha-and-skapaid).

Comment: Check again . You have to init the listview and change the id of listview in layout file